# In Highcharts, How to generate Column Drilldown chart with random numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, drilldown

In highchart, Drilldown Column chart we have. In this I want to generate data randomly.

For example : Number is 300.
Then for this drilldown no. of data are 4. Hence need to divide this 300 into such a ways that where 4 no.s total should be 300. 
Or add 4 numbers(drilldown data) and generate root number which will be 300.

How can we do this?

Comment: How it should be distributed? I mean if you have 300, which values should be? Totally random like 0,0,0,300 (edge example) or 100,100,50,50 ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan: I am using Math.round(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum); minimum and maximum will enter and random numbers should not repeat.  Thanks.

Comment: So what kind of problem do you have, can you recraete your example as live demo  on the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/ This is the link of example I am referring. For example : On x-axis "Microsoft Internet Explorer" for this label, y axis data value is "56.3%" , So When I click on "Microsoft Internet Explorer" this then I get drilldown data with 24.1%, 17.2%, 8.1%, 5.3%, 1.1%, 0.5% with x-axis data "v11.0, v8.0, etc". So I want to generate this % data values randomly.